# Upload and delete picture with PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am building a page that allows me to upload and delete the picture. Also, I can view the picture on that page. For now, I am able to upload the picture and the picture will be stored in my C: drive folder and the records will be uploaded to MySql. However, I am not able to delete the picture and view the picture on the page. I am not sure the reasons for these. I guess the problem maybe the naming and the file location for the pictures.

When I upload the picture, the naming in the C: drive will be changed it to according to the time as the name. The naming for the records in MySql will still remain the same.  [image]

[image]

I am not sure how to convert these two images to the same name and provide a path in MySql that allow me to show the image so as to delete my pictures.

The code for my page is below:

```
 <div class="container">
            <?php
            include "config.php";

            if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
                //////
                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                    echo "Error: :{$_FILES["file"]["error"]}<br>";
                } else {


                    $allowdExts = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];
                    $filenameStrArr = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    $extension = strtolower(end($filenameStrArr));
                    ////-----------------------------
                    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                    ///-------------------------------
                    $allowedTypes = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/pjpeg"];
                    $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
                    $sizeLimit = 2000;
                    $fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024;  //divide to get size in kb
                    if (in_array($extension, $allowdExts) &&
                            in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes) &&
                            ($fileSize <= $sizeLimit)) {

                        $distDir = "../uploads/";
                        $distFilename = "pic_" . time() . ".{$extension}";
                        $upload = $distDir . "/" . $distFilename;

                        //$distFinal = "upload/" . $_FILES["myFile"]["name"];    
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload);
                    }
                }

                /*
                  $file = '../uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                  $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file); */

                if ($upload) {
                    $add = $db->prepare("insert into upload values('',?)");
                    $add->bindParam(1, $name);
                    if ($add->execute()) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Success!</strong> File upload successful to database.
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Failed!</strong> File upload unsuccessful to database.
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <strong>Sorry!</strong> File upload unsuccessful .
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">Upload File</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                    <p class="help-block">This will be the picture you upload.</p>
                </div>   
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
            </form>

            <p><br/></p>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
                    $img = $_GET['remove'];
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $remove = unlink('uploads'.$img);
                    if ($remove) {
                        $rmv = $db->prepare("delete from upload where id='$id'");
                        if ($rmv->execute()) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <strong>Success!</strong> File removed from directory and database .
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <strong>Failed!</strong> File failed erased from database.
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Error!</strong> File is not erased from directory.
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }

                $stmt = $db->prepare("select * from upload");
                $stmt ->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img style="height:200px;"src="uploads<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" alt="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" title="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>">
                            <div class="caption text-center">
                                <p><a href="?remove=<?php echo$row['foto'] ?> &id<?php echo$row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Which server are you using? Keep your images local to your project folder and ensure you are specifying the correct path to each image. You can store the full image path in your DB or have a static path defined in your script and append each file name retrieved from the DB

Answer (score 1):

**1. you should make your delete query more save.**

```
$rmv = $db->prepare("delete from upload where id=:file_id");
$rmv->bindValue(':file_id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**2. Then, you maybe forgot a slash in the delete file line.**

change

```
$remove = unlink('uploads'.$img);
```

to

```
$remove = unlink('uploads/'.$img);
```

I would also recommend you, that you read your file path only from your database and not by a get request. You are already getting the id for the file right? Use the file id as the main key, not the file name.

**3. there is also a missing / in the line you try to show the images**
change

```
<img style="height:200px;"src="uploads<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" alt="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" title="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>">
```

to

```
<img style="height:200px;"src="uploads/<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" alt="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>" title="<?php echo$row['foto'] ?>">
```